How to calculate TDR @ % FDR 0.02?
how do I calculate TDR (%) @ FDR = 0.02% in Python?
I have found the ROC curve and stored the fprs, tprs , threshold and interpret the value of tpr at different fpr values but the problem is there a difference between TDR @ %FDR and TPR @ % FPR and if there is a difference how can i get the array of TDR's and FDR's

To calculate TDR at FDR of 0.02%, you'd typically need a dataset or results from a model. Assuming you have the number of true positives (TP), false positives (FP), true negatives (TN), and false negatives (FN), you can calculate TDR and FDR as follows:
TDR = TP ÷ (TP + FN)
FDR = FP ÷ (FP + TP)
def calculate_tdr(tp, fn):
    return tp / (tp + fn)

def calculate_fdr(fp, tp):
    return fp / (tp + fp)

# Example values
tp = 90
fn = 10
fp = 2

tdr = calculate_tdr(tp, fn)
fdr = calculate_fdr(fp, tp)

print(f"TDR: {tdr*100:.2f}%")
print(f"FDR: {fdr*100:.2f}%")


Thanks Jamie, but does the area under the curve make sense when i plot TDR vs FDR ? i don't know what TDR vs. FDR actually represent. and interestingly their sum is not equal to 1 , they are not complement of each other
